# Dynamic change of marker based on value in KML file

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using KML file to overlay my data on google map . Actually I want to change the marker color based on some value which in the KML file .

How can I do that .

Comment: What value in the KML file?  Are you displaying the map on http://maps.google.com?  Can you use a Google Maps API v3 map (you have added that tag to the question).  KML supports [styling the icons](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#icon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: KML supports the styling of icons, but the `<color>`-element is not supported for `<iconStyle>` by the Maps-API, so you cannot change the color of an Icon(see https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps for more details).

What you can do is use different icon-images with the desired colors.

But afaik there is no "dynamic" way to change the `<href>` of an `<icon>`.

However, you may create a serverside script that parses the original KML and delivers a modified KML to google.