# dynamic marker position google map

Tags: google-maps, kml

As marinetraffic.com, I would like to display a list of my products position on google map (via a joomla plugin - Phoca Maps). 
Via a private database I can generate regurlarly an up-to-date kml (myproducts.kml) file with the position of my products (some appear and some disappear).

The myproducts.kml file is re-computed every night.

Could you make, for me, a simple sample code which permits to see the changements on google map every day.
Do i need more than 2 files (the first one containing Networklink as I can see et the second one is myproducts.kml) ?

Thanks in advance
Jean-Christophe

Comment: see this blog post http://xyzzyb.tumblr.com/post/10317033064/dynamically-loading-thousands-of-markers-in-google-maps

Comment: and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494175/dynamic-change-of-marker-based-on-value-in-kml-file